# How does Mono closes file handles on OSX? ("Too many open files" issue)

Tags: macos, mono

I'm currently porting .Net application to OSX and having problem with application crashing on "Too many open files" exception. I was able to find out that OSX has 256 open files limit (by default) per application and my application exceeds this limit in some situations. However I'm unable to find out why the OSX thinks that I'm leaving files open.

For example this simple command leaves all files in directory open even that I'm not opening them per say:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("/Users/test/MonoDebug/")
```

I'm checking list of open files via:

```
lsof -c mono
```

Does anybody know how to prevent this? Is this normal Mono behavior?

OSX 10.9.5, Mono 3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found a resource-leak in Mono source code?

The `GetFiles()` method is implemented under the hood as an internal call (C code). Then you should be looking at [io.c](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/io.c), maybe a call to `FindClose()` function is missing somewhere?